# sendmessage does not work

Tags: c++, sendmessage

I try to sendmessage to an IE rebar/toolbar, but it seems that my toolbar does not take the message effect. Can someone tell me where is the fault ?

```
HRESULT CButtonDemoBHO::onDocumentComplete(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *vUrl)     
{           
    m_hWnd = NULL;
    SHANDLE_PTR nBrowser = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = m_spWebBrowser2->get_HWND(&nBrowser);
    m_hWnd = (HWND)nBrowser;
    SendMessage(m_hWnd, WM_test, 0, 0);
    return S_OK;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stronly recommned that you check the values of `hr` and `m_hWnd` and the return value of `sendmessage()`.   I doubt that "Send message does not work", but am willing to believe "my message does not arrive".  Are you sure that you are sending it to a valid destination?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to wrap the call to `SendMessage` between `SetLastError()` and `GetLastError()`, like so...

```
SetLastError(0);
LRESULT rv = SendMessage(m_hWnd, WM_test, 0, 0);
DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
if(errCode != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    // log error information here.
}
```

The return value from SendMessage depends on what WM_test returns from the handling function, so I would check the docs for that message too.

You can usually get a human-readable error message by passing the error code that GetLastError() returns as the dwMessageId parameter in  `FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, ...)`.

[FormatMessage docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(VS.85).aspx).